# C++ Vectors initialization

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

```
#include <vector>
...
//inside main function
vector<int> vi3 = {42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42};
```

I'm learning C++, I thought it was possible to initialize a vector like this... Am I doing something wrong? I know about the other ways of initializing a vector. In the book I'm reading it says it can also be done like this:

```
vector<int> vi3{42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42,42};
```

It's the first thing on the book that gave me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to tell your compiler you are using C++11.

Comment: And make sure it's not visual studio < the 2013 beta, since it's not implemented til then

Comment: @SadSeven which compiler are you using?

Comment: @tronjanfoe Really? I'm using the last Visual Studio and g++ on Linux. I haven't tried it on g++ yet. Do I have to change anything on g++?

Comment: @SadSeven Yeah provide the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @SadSeven: In general, we have a better chance of helping you if you include the error message. (And google that message first)

Comment: @SadSeven: As other said, and even if the question is already answer, you should include the error message you got, it will make this Q&A useful for other people. I promise a +1 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear which compiler you are using, but versions of Microsoft's Visual Studio before the 2013 preview do not support the uniform initialisation syntax `{}`

If you are using gcc you need to tell it to use C++11:

```
-std=c++0x
```

Comment: The CTP did, but did not have library support. `-std=c++11` has a couple of advantages over `-std=c++0x` as well.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, sorry. You're right. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good point Chris. This will depend on the version of gcc too, right?